# How do I switch back and forth between columns in Libreoffice writer?

Tags: navigation

How do I after setting up for two columns using Libreoffice writer get the cursor to go to the right hand column so I can enter text on the right side?

Answer (score 3):

[Looks like](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/5744/how-to-move-between-columns-in-a-writer-document/) columns don't work like that, they fill in everything on one side, then move to the next side.

If you want to artificially enter a column break, it's under *"Insert > Manual Break ... > Column break"*

Using a table or text frame is probably closer to what you desire.